# Unexpected Token in Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am getting the following error when I try to upload a firebase functions

> Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> /private/var/folders/_5/96_hf2sx4dj69gzfm6bz9fl80000gn/T/fbfn_62815Dgk529e7Q94f/index.js:94
>           if (current_value - 1) >= 0 {
>                                  ^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token >=

the code is as follows

```
exports.countFollowing2 = functions.database.ref('/{pushId}/following/')
    .onDelete(event => {

      event.data.ref.parent.child('following_count').transaction(function (current_value) {

        if (current_value - 1) >= 0 {
          return (current_value - 1);
        }
        else{
          return 0;
        }

      });


    });
```

I'm assuming I'm doing something stupid and its a simple fix but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `if (current_value - 1) >= 0 {` with `if ((current_value-1) >= 0) {`.

The important difference is that parenthesis must enclose the entire condition. This is different from Swift (if you come from that background), where having parenthesis around the condition itself are optional.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you come from a Swift background?

Comment: Yup, from swift